# Agregar array dentro de otro array

Tags: php, array, while

tengo el siguiente codigo en php

```
    $statement = $conexion->prepare("SELECT * FROM propiedades ORDER BY id ASC");

    $statement->execute();

$resultados = [];
while ($row = $statement->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    $usuario = [
        "id" => $row['id'],
        "provincia" => $row['provincia'],
        "ntabla" => $row['ntabla'],
        "img" => ''
    ];
    array_push($resultados,$usuario);
    $portada = $row['ntabla'];
    // $portada = '22_89_12022019135725';
    $statement_p = $conexion->prepare("SELECT * FROM $portada WHERE id = 1 LIMIT 1 ");
    $statement_p->execute();
    $resultados_p = [];
    while ($row_p = $statement_p->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
        $usuario_p =  $row_p['imagen'];
        array_push($resultados, ['img' => $usuario_p]);


}
}
header("Content-type:application/json; charset = utf-8");
$json["data"] = array_values($resultados);
echo json_encode($json);
exit();
```

El problema es que el array_push me agrega el array como un objeto mas, lo que quiero es que me lo agregue al arreglo data, en el cual tengo id, provincia y quisiera que entre uno que diga imagen y sea el resultado del while.

Desde ya muchas gracias

Comment: Quieres que el resultado se vea algo asi? array(1) { [0]=> array(4) { ["id"]=> string(1) "1" ["provincia"]=> string(9) "provincia" ["ntabla"]=> string(6) "ntabla" ["img"]=> string(11) "una imagen?" } }

Comment: claro, lo acabo de solucionar. Lo que hice fue corregir el while de $usuarios_p, lo que quedo fue:
$usuario['img'] = $row_p['imagen'];
entonces me coloca como un elemento mas.
Gracias por tu respuesta